# 'net ads join -U username' failing with an error 'NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT'

Tags: ubuntu, samba, active-directory, ntp, kerberos

I am attempting to provide access to Ubuntu shared directories using Active Directory users and group using Samba. I am following [this article](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/SAMBA_Share_with_Active_Directory_Login_on_Ubuntu_12.04.html) to install and configure AD and Unix so that access can be provided:

**Summary**

1. As a part of the installation, I have installed `ntp krb5-user samba(v4.1.6) samba-common smbclient winbind`
2. I followed the configuration settings as provided in the above article. I have configured `ntp.conf`, `resolv.conf`, `krb5.conf`, `nsswitch.conf` and `smb.conf`.
3. After restarting all of the services and while joining the domain using `sudo net ads join -U administrator`, I am getting the following error:

   Failed to join domain: failed to lookup DC info for domain 'CELESTIAL1' over rpc: NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT

**Testing**

1. I tried to execute `kinit username`, the ticket got generated successfully and I was able to verify from command 'klist'.
2. I am able to ping the Ubuntu server's IP and the Windows server's IP as well as the domain from both the sides.
3. The services `winbind`, `nmbd`, and `smbd` are running as expected.
4. I rebooted the Ubuntu machine and AD server, but same error is showing while performing the domain join operation.

**Questions**

1. What does the `NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT` error indicate? Are there any issues on the Windows Server or on Ubuntu machine?
2. How can I join the Ubuntu machine to Active Directory? Are there any steps that I missed that need to be performed to join the domain successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there was no entry in `/etc/resolv.conf` for AD DNS and hence the machine was pinging to the actual global registered domain. On each reboot, the `resolv.conf` entries gets reset hence we have to provide entry once the system is rebooted.

Comment: Alternatively, you can provide a dns-nameservers in /etc/network/interfaces or use some other persistent way of storing preferred DNS servers